# Create a button to remotely trigger an imageswap in a gallery (without repeating a ton of code for each image)

Tags: jquery, image, triggers, dry, swap

I will try to be as clear as possible here.

I started with the format of "EFFECT 2" on this demo page. 
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index2.html
(find the source code here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/)

What I would like ideally is to create an effect where when you click on the "Take a look" button in the caption, it triggers the image in that div to change from one image to an alternate image.

The trouble here is that I don't want to have to repeat a ton of code over and over again for each image. Is there a simple way to do this so it applies to all of these elements? (I'm trying to stick to the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) philosophy.

I'm having trouble understanding how to achieve this as I am pretty new with JQuery. I managed to achieve this effect with a hover effect, but am having trouble figuring out how to identify and get an image and swap that particular image for another from a remote button. Normally for a hover effect, one could just use $(this).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.cs-style-2 figcaption a").click(function(clickEvent){
        // Find the containing figure
        var parentFigure = $(this).closest("figure");          

        // Find the child image
        var figureImage = parentFigure.children("img");

        // Change the image's src attribute
        figureImage.attr("src", "http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/images/6.png");

        clickEvent.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You can add an alternate image src to the image using a data-altsrc attribute, then retrieve it with figureImage.attr("data-altsrc")

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! It works! There's only one thing. I'm trying to get the button to toggle the image. I have tried this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ipiyale/Eagch/2/

Can you give me any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your answer Patrick! I've figured out the last part with some "fiddling" (excuse the pun).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul.cs-style-2 figcaption a").click(function(clickEvent){
    var parentFigure = $(this).closest("figure");        
    var figureImage = parentFigure.children("img");
    var originalSrc = figureImage.attr("src");
    var altSrc = figureImage.attr("data-altsrc");

    if(altSrc) {
      figureImage.attr("src", altSrc); 
      figureImage.attr("data-altsrc", originalSrc); //Added this part and it worked!
      clickEvent.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

});